# Change TextView from AsyncTask messages from diffrent class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using `AsyncTask` to run my bash script in Android:

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> doInBackground(String... params){
//some code...            
ProcessScript processScript = new ProcessScript();

            processScript.setActivity(activity);
            processScript.runScript();

            this.publishProgress(processScript.getLine());
//some code..
return statusMap;
}

 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        TextView display = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.LogView);
        display.setText(values[0]);

        Log.d("lab", "onPUP: " + values[0]);
    }
```

`runScript`function runs the script, then the function runScript print output information generated by the script. I wish that this information was immediately passed to the `onProgressUpdate` and wonder how it can be done.
Code from my `ProcessScript` class:

```
//some code 

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.d("lab", line);
                    setLine(line);
                }
```

This code works, but shows me ONLY THE LAST line of the log. How to improve it to function `onProgresUpdate` listened to a loop while from `ProcessScript` that prints the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publishProgress should be inside your loop if you expect to see multiple progress values

Comment: How can I do if the loop is in a different class, not in the class `AsyncTask`?